# Cassandra isolation in same row-key mutation

Tags: cassandra

We know that,batch statement with operations to same row key is isolated.

Is this is applicable for Insert,Update and Delete mutations.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra supports [row-level isolation](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/row-level-isolation) since 1.1. This applies to all mutations under the same partition key.