# How single partition batch in Cassandra function for multiple column update?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

We have multiple update queries in a single partition of a single columnfamily. Like below

```
update t1 set username = 'abc', url = 'www.something.com', age = ? where userid = 100;
update t1 set username = 'abc', url = 'www.something.com', weight = ? where userid = 100;
update t1 set username = 'abc', url = 'www.something.com', height = ? where userid = 100;
```

`username`, `url` will be always same and are mandatory fields. But depending on the information given there will be extra columns.

As this is a single partition operation and we need atomicity + isolation. We will execute this in a batch.

As per Doc

> A BATCH statement combines multiple data modification language (DML) statements (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) into a single logical operation, and sets a client-supplied timestamp for all columns written by the statements in the batch.

Now as we are updating columns(username, url) with same value in multiple statement, will C* combines it as a single statement before executing it like

```
update t1 set username = 'abc', url = 'www.something.com', age = ?, weight = ?, height = ? where userid = 100;
```

or same value will be upsert?

Another question is that, as they all have the same timestamp how C* resolves that conflict. Will C* compare every column (username, url) value.

> As they all have the same timestamp C* resolves the conflict by choosing the largest value for the cells. [Atomic Batch in Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572831/atomic-batch-in-cassandra)

Or should we add queries in batch like below. In this case we have to check username, url has already been added in statement.

```
update t1 set username = 'abc', url = 'www.something.com', age = ? where userid = 100;
update t1 set weight = ? where userid = 100;
update t1 set height = ? where userid = 100;
```

In short what will be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question(will C* combines it as a single statement?) answer is yes.

A single partition batch is applied as a single row mutation.

check this link for details:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6737

For your second question(Will C* compare every column (username, url) value?) answer is also yes.

As given in the answer of your provided [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30579176/6752274) "Conflict is resolved by choosing the largest value for the cells"

So, you can write queries in batch in either way(given in your question). 
As it will ultimately converted to a single write internally.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Single partition batch so everything goes into a single partition.**So all of your update will be merge and applied with a single RowMutation**.

And so your update will be applied with no batch log, atomic, isolated

Comment: So that means C* merges those queries and makes it single and executes it as a single row mutation?

Comment: Yes. So all of your update will be merge and applied with a single RowMutation. (Edited the answer)